# Keras Dense layer is showing too many parameters on kaggle

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

```py
def my_model():
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(height,width,3))
    x = layers.Conv2D(32,3)(inputs)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization(input_shape=(32,32,3))(x)
    x = keras.activations.tanh(x)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(5,5),padding="valid")(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = keras.activations.tanh(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(filters=128,kernel_size=(3,3),padding="valid")(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.Flatten()(x)
    x = layers.Dense(64,activation="tanh")(x)
    outputs = layers.Dense(35)(x)
    
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs = x)
    return model
```

```py
model = my_model()
model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=3e-4),
    metrics=["accuracy"]
)
model.summary()
```

this results in output:

Model: "functional_11"

---

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

input_7 (InputLayer)         [(None, 200, 200, 3)]     0

---

conv2d_18 (Conv2D)           (None, 198, 198, 32)      896

---

batch_normalization_18 (Batc (None, 198, 198, 32)      128

---

tf_op_layer_Tanh_12 (TensorF [(None, 198, 198, 32)]    0

---

max_pooling2d_6 (MaxPooling2 (None, 99, 99, 32)        0

---

conv2d_19 (Conv2D)           (None, 95, 95, 64)        51264

---

batch_normalization_19 (Batc (None, 95, 95, 64)        256

---

tf_op_layer_Tanh_13 (TensorF [(None, 95, 95, 64)]      0

---

conv2d_20 (Conv2D)           (None, 93, 93, 128)       73856

---

batch_normalization_20 (Batc (None, 93, 93, 128)       512

---

flatten_6 (Flatten)          (None, 1107072)           0

---

dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 64)                70852672

---

## dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 35)                2275

Total params: 70,981,859
Trainable params: 70,981,411
Non-trainable params: 448

---

Here, dense_6 layer with 64 units is showing a huge number of parameters.
I'm using kaggle, can somebody help me out by pointing out my mistake?

Comment: The number of parameters of a Dense layer depends both on the number of neurons and # of input features, so there is nothing wrong here.

Comment: There is no mistake, the input to the dense layer (output of flatten) is huge, over a million units (93*93*128). You can add more pooling layers (or increase the stride of the existing pooling/conv layers) to make the feature maps smaller. E.g. if you downsize by 4x more (to 23x23), you'd only have ~4 million parameters in the dense layer.

Comment: thank you, I did not know that, I thought there's some mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal, you have a 1,107,072 neurons fully connected to 64 neurons. So the number of parameters is equal to :

- input_length * output_length + output_length = 1,107,072 * 64 + 64 = 70,852,672.

If it's too much for your problem, you should reduce the size before the `flatten()` layer. For instance, use more pooling layers or calculate less filters.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this part for me, i'm just starting out in this field. I just couldn't figure it out by myself.